# How to print the passed multidimensional array from controller to view in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having a problem in accessing/creating a foreach statement when using a multidimensional array.

In my controller I have the following:

```
$data = array();    
$temp = array();
           ...
    some codes here
           ...
array_push($data, $temp);
$this->load->view('view', $data);
```

The $data array contains something like this:

```
Array(
[0]=>
    Array(
        [information]=>
            Array(
                [name]=>John Doe
                [age] =>21
            )
        [data]=>
            Array(
                [earnings]=>
                    Array(
                        [salary]=>21000
                        [bonus]=>1000
                        )
                [deductions]=>
                    Array(
                        [tax]=>1000
                        [loan]=>0
                    )
            )
    )
[1]=>
    Array(
        [information]=>
            Array(
                [name]=>George Read
                [age] =>23
            )
        [data]=>
            Array(
                [earnings]=>
                    Array(
                        [salary]=>20000
                        [bonus]=>1000
                        )
                [deductions]=>
                    Array(
                        [tax]=>990
                        [loan]=>200
                    )
            )
    )
```

)

What should I do in view to be able to print/echo the data? Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Give us an example of the code you are using in your view now

Comment: Don't you just use the indexed values like $name, $earnings, and so forth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to access a variable that's been assigned to `$data` in the controller, you use the index of the array as a variable. So if you wanted to echo out the variable in the view, you'd use

```
echo $0['information']['name'];
```

If you wanted to use a Foreach loop, you could use a nested foreach loop. But in that case, it would be better to assign the `$temp` array to a specific variable in the controller

**Controller**

```
$data['temp_array'] = $temp;
```

Then the foreach loop would look like this:

**View**

```
foreach ($temp_array as $array_name => $array) {
    echo $array_name;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        echo $key ': ' . $value;
    }
}
```

See [this page](http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/01/php-arrays-array-functions-and-multidimensional-arrays/) for info on looping through multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

First of all define your array in the controller file something like this:

```
$array = array(
                        0 => array(
                                "foo" => "bar",
                                  42    => 24,
                                "multi" => array(
                                        "dimensional" => array(
                                            "array" => "foo"
                                                        )
                                                )
                                    ),
                        1 => array(
                                "foo" => "bar",
                                   42    => 24,
                                "multi" => array(
                                        "dimensional" => array(
                                                        "array" => "foo"
                                                                )
                                                )
                                    )

                );
```

Now the question is, how to access [0]or[1]!
to do that assign this array to $data['arbitrary_variable']

In the view file you could directly use this $arbitrary_variable as array.

Controller Code:

```
public function index() {

 $data['magic'] =  $array = array(
                        0 => array(
                                "foo" => "bar",
                                  42    => 24,
                                "multi" => array(
                                        "dimensional" => array(
                                            "array" => "foo"
                                                        )
                                                )
                                    ),
                        1 => array(
                                "foo" => "bar",
                                   42    => 24,
                                "multi" => array(
                                        "dimensional" => array(
                                                        "array" => "foo"
                                                                )
                                                )
                                    )

                );


    $this->load->view('test',$data);
}
```

View Code:

```
<?php

print_r($magic);

echo '<br/>';

echo $magic[0]['foo'];

?>
```

**The idea here is to put your desired array into yet another array, i.e. not to assign it directly to $data but to a key of data**

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following changes:

1) You should try to add an element to the data array you are passing to the view, so you can access the element and loop it.

```
$data = array();    
$temp = array();
    //some codes here
array_push($data['anametoaccess'][], $temp);    //this will give us a element name to access and loop the array
$this->load->view('view', $data);
```

2) This is the code for the view:

```
foreach( $anametoaccess as $key => $each ){
    $information        = $each['information']; //now you have the information array in $informationarray
    $earnings           = $each['data']['earnings']; 
    $deductions         = $each['data']['deductions'];
}
```